# Set default width and min width property

Tags: html, css

I am showing images in a dialog with images of varying size , the minimum width image being of 500px and most of images are greater than 800px wide.

```
.modal-dialog { min-width:500px; }
```

How do I applying css properties such that if image is 500px wide orless than 800px , the width of container dialog `.modal-dialog` decreases to image width but remains fixed at 800px for other images of size greater than 800px.

Similarly suggest how to do this for height.

Comment: are you use max width properties? try with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.modal_dialog img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;  
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

now you set the height for that images

Comment: if you apply `display: inline-block`,  the image will not be in center. Apply `display: block` and use `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: @user3353643 The above solution works !! But how can I make my dialog appear at center of screen.

Comment: @mmhasannn try Mr_Green's comment

Comment: Add <center> to that img or add position and adjust where you need

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following properties to the container `.modal.dialog`:

```
.modal_dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;  
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

`max-width` and `max-height` constrain the container to the required dimensions and setting the display to `inline-block` and the width to `auto` will adjust the container width to the image width if it is between 500px and 800px.

Comment: Thanks for explanation , solution works . But earlier my dialog was appearing in center , now it has shiftedto left of screen , how to make it appear in center ?

Comment: You don't actually need to set `width: auto` because it's the default. Just don't set a width. Or height.